# split big matrix in subsets,R

Tags: r

I would like to make subgroups for a matrix， and each subgroup contains the same amount of column. For example, there is a matrix with 1000 rows and 420 columns, and I would like to split into 35 sub-matrix in order, like first one contains the first 12 cols, and the second contains the second 12 cols, and so on. I think I could use function Iris. Please help me!

```
iris[c()]
```

Comment: Can you please share a reproducible example? `iris` is a dataset not a function.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if this is what you're after, but here's a reproducible example:

```
# Define matrix
M = matrix( 
     c(1:20), 
     nrow=2, 
     ncol=10) 

# Split into 5 submatrices of equal size
lapply(split(M, rep(1:5, each = 4)), matrix, ncol = 2)
$`1`
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    3
[2,]    2    4

$`2`
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    5    7
[2,]    6    8

$`3`
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    9   11
[2,]   10   12

$`4`
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]   13   15
[2,]   14   16

$`5`
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]   17   19
[2,]   18   20
```

Comment: Thanks mtoto for answering! Regarding to your example of matrix M, If I would like to split the big matrix M into 5 sub-matrix but with different sizes, such as the first matrix contains the first 4 values, the second contains the first 8 values ( includes the first matrix), the third contains the first 12 values ( include both first and second matrix)  and so on... Until I got the whole big matrix. How could I do this? Thanks

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask in a new post instead of trying to update existing ones.

Answer (score 3):

You can turn your 1000 × 420 matrix into a 1000 × 12 × 35 matrix with

```
dim(x) <- c(1000, 12, 35)
```

where `x` is the original matrix.  Then `x[, , 1]` gives you the first 1000 × 12 sub-matrix, `x[, , 2]` the second sub-matrix, and so forth.